# How do I create a QUOTENAME function in mySQL

Tags: mysql, function

I would like to create a QUOTENAME() function in mySQL like the one that exists in M$ SQL Server.

This is what it does:

> QUOTENAME returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make
> the input string a valid identifier. The QUOTENAME function uses this
> syntax:
>
> ```
> QUOTENAME ( 'string' [ , 'delimiter' ] )
> ```
>
> You pass QUOTENAME a string to be delimited and a one-character string
> to use as the delimiter. The delimiter can be a square bracket or a
> single or double quotation mark.

Is this even possible?

Comment: +1 Good question. If you just want to quote a value, there's always [`QUOTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote), but for identifiers I've up to now used `CONCAT('\`', REPLACE(str, '\`', '\`\`'), '\`')` which I've never felt *completely* happy with...

Comment: Also reserved words and identifiers with special characters have to be quoted with a '`'.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this - building off of eggyal's comment

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS QUOTENAME;

CREATE FUNCTION QUOTENAME (s varchar(50), d CHAR(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR(52)
RETURN CONCAT (d, REPLACE(s, d, CONCAT(d,d)), d);
```

And then add your special cases and additional functionality.